# Jquery accordion change link function after second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got a simple accordion, and was wondering how to change the link after the second click so it goes to the actual URL. 
So the first click opens the accordion, which is working fine, then the second click goes to the href.

My accordion code is

```
$(".mobile-main-nav ul ul").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            header: "a.level2"
        });
```

I know the `event:false` option would disable the click event, but am unsure what the best method is to apply it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have

Comment: Sure, so I literally have something like this right now ... http://jsfiddle.net/P6JeF/ , so after you click on the first accordion header, it opens, but then the next time you click the link, I'd like it to go to the actual page.

Comment: Let me see if I am understanding this correctly. For the header (expander), when a panel is collapsed, you want the first click to expand the section and on second click, you want it to use the link. What about on the third click? And clicks after?

Comment: Yep, that's correct, the third click wouldn't matter it would have navigated away from the page by then, because the second click links to the page. Sorry if that sounds a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the 'beforeActivate' event of the accordion to attach a flag attribute to the element.  Run this through a conditional and you should get something close to what you want.

```
$("ul.testnav").accordion({
collapsible: true,
active: false,
beforeActivate: function(e, ui){
    if(ui.newHeader.attr('data-visited')){
        window.location = ui.newHeader.attr('href');
    } else {
         ui.newHeader.attr('data-visited', 'true');
    }
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/P6JeF/1/ (The actual linking won't work as jsFiddle doesn't have a 'page1.html')

Comment: Thanks for that, quite close to what I want, although when I use it in the actual code it returns 'undefined' sometimes, and I'd like it to work for each individual accordion rather than altogether. E.g. if I click on the first accord, then click the second accord, I'd still like the second to open, not redirect because its still the first time I clicked on it.

Comment: Sounds close thou, I'd give it an +1 if i had enough rep!

Comment: That works much better, thanks, although now you need to click the first accordion 3 times for it to go to the link. Sorry for the fussyness! But I'll mark it as the solution because it works otherwise.

Comment: I must be confused about the UI experience you're looking for.  :)  Play around with the parameters that are returned in the ui object in the beforeActivate function.  I was using the 'newHeader' element.  You may want to reference some combination of the 'newHeader' and 'oldHeader' in order to nail down the exact functionality you want.

Comment: Will do, I need to work on my Javascripting techniques anyway, thanks for your help :)